# How to set a response variant on DialogFlow using their REST API

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create text variants using the /intents API resource mentioned here:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents

However, it seems that there is not a way to do such thing. if I send the JSON as:

```
"responses": [
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "speech": "Okay response variant 01",
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "speech": "Okay response variant 02",
      "type": 0
    }
  ],
```

it creates 2 full response text messages instead of a text variant, do you know what I could be missing on the JSON to create the responses as text variant?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know it was decades ago, but I happened to come across and wanted to quickly leave this example. Maybe it will help the next person who looks in here. :)

```
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "0",
      "title": "",
      "textToSpeech": "",
      "lang": "en",
      "speech": [
        "Okay response variant 01",
        "Okay response variant 02",
        "Okay response variant 03"
      ],
      "condition": ""
    }
  ],
```